# button click to make JInternalFrame appear once even when minimized

Tags: java, swing

this code below makes JInternalFrame pop-up on a JDesktopPane within a JFrame

```
JInternalPane adf = new JInternalpane();
JDesktopPane.add(adf);
adf.show();
```

but when the InternalFrame is iconified or still visible on the DesktopPane and the Action_Button that makes the InternalFrame to show is clicked again, another InternalFrame of the same type pops-up again. and keeps poping up as many times as the button is clicked.
please how can we generate a code such that if a button is clicked, it should first check if the internalFrame is iconified and make it rather visible again. rather than poping up another internalframe.
I am using netbeans ide with jdk 8.
the button_action is performed when i right-click the button, select EVENTS,then ACTION PERFORMED, where i have only this code written so far.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
JInternalPane adf = new JInternalpane();
JDesktopPane.add(adf);
adf.show();
// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
```

thank you

Comment: I think you sould add more code so we can help

Comment: Don't keep creating a `new JInternalFrame()`.

Comment: so how should I write it @camickr

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep an instance variable for the internal frame so you know the current state.

Then the code in the ActionListener would be something like:

```
if (internalFrame == null) // not yet created
{
    internalFrame = new JInternalFrame(...);
    desktopPane.add( internalFrame );
    internalFrame.show();
}
else if (internal frame is iconified) // read the API for the method to use
{
    //  show the internal frame
}
```